# High clustering coefficient and large average path length in one graph

Tags: graph-theory

Can somebody provide an example of a network with a high clustering coefficient and a large average path length? A visual representation of such a network would be great.

No reason for asking, besides that I think it would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of a graph with a number of big clumps of complete graph, then the clumps are connected by long chains.  Most vertices will be in a clump, but the average distance will be dominated by the long distance between the clumps.

Comment: great, thanks :)